# Loadin angular rest

Tags: angularjs, rest

Supongamos q tengo el sgte controlador :

test.controller

```
App.controller('TestController', ['$scope', '$http', '$resource' , 'InitService', function($scope, $http, $resource, InitService) { 
$scope.createProduct = function(product) {
    InitService.createProduct(product).then(
        function(d) {
            $scope.product = d;
        }
    );
}

$scope.createProduct2 = function(product2) {
    InitService.createProduct2(product2).then(
        function(d) {
            $scope.product = d;
        }
    );
}
```

y el servicio test.service

```
App.factory('InitService', ['$http','$q',function($http, $q) {
var REST_SERVICE_URI = 'http://localhost:8090/test/databases';

return {
    createProduct : function(product) {
        return $http({
             method: 'POST',
             url: REST_SERVICE_URI + "/product1",
             data: product,
            }).then(function success(response) {
                return response.data;
            }, function error(response) {

            });
    },
    createProduct2 : function(product) {
        return $http({
             method: 'POST',
             url: REST_SERVICE_URI + "/product2",
             data: product,
            }).then(function success(response) {
                return response.data;
            }, function error(response) {

            });
    },
```

Como se podria hacer para que cada llamada rest salga un loading?, habia pensado en un $scope.showLoading, pero ponerlo en cada método no seria elegante, alguna otra sugerencia?

Gracias

Comment: Puedes utilizar **SweetAlert2** de Limonte. Creo que no necesita explicación porque es muy sencillo de utilizar: https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/

Comment: No se a que te refieres con "poco elegante" cuando seria lo más logico hacer el `show` cuando llamas a la funcion y el `hide` cuando esto termina.

Comment: si pero si lo tengo que hacer cada vez que llame una funcion, imaginate que tenga 1000 funciones, serian lineas de codigo que creo que sobrarian y no es elegante

Comment: te deje un respuesta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres realizar esto, tendrias que desarrollar un `Interceptor`, que como su nombre lo dice, intercepta estas llamadas tanto sincronas como asincronas antes de entregar algun tipo de respuesta.

El valor de `$q` basicamente es un servicio que sirve o ayuda a que cuando se ejecutan tareas asincronas puedas manejar sus valores de retorno.

```
.factory('HttpInterceptor', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$timeout', function($rootScope, $q, $timeout) {

    return {
        'request': function(config) {

            $timeout(function() {
                $rootScope.isLoading = true; 
            }, 200);

            return config || $q.when(config);
        },
        'requestError': function(rejection) {
            /*...*/
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        },
        'response': function(response) {

            $rootScope.isLoading = false; 

            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            /*...*/
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
}])
```

Luego en tu configuración seteas este `Interceptor`

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpInterceptor');
}])
```

Y finalmente el valor de tu loading

```
<div class="loading" ng-show="isLoading"></div>
```

Queda de parte tuya diseñar el loading tal como lo quieres, si un gif o algo asi!

Answer (score 0):

Que fácil lo ves @sioesi pero yo no tanto, tengo los siguientes ficheros:

test_controler.js

```
var App = angular.module('SimulatorApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngMaterial', 'ngAria', 'ngResource']);

App.controller('EOGController', ['$scope', '$http', '$resource' , 'InitService', function($scope, $http, $resource, InitService) {  
$scope.isLoading = false;
..... aquí las funciones
}]);

App.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpInterceptor');
}])
```

test_service.js

```
App.factory('InitService', ['$http','$q',function($http, $q) {
    var REST_SERVICE_URI = 'http://localhost:8090/test/databases';
...y aqui las funciones que que el controlador llama
```

filter_service.js:

```
Tengo exactamente lo que me has puesto
```

index.html:

```
isLoading : {{isLoading}}
<div class="loading" ng-show="isLoading">testing</div>
```

El valor de isLoading siempre esta en false

Comment: en tu controlador defines $scope.isLoading = false, mientras que en mi ejemplo no se define asi, se define $rootScope.isLoading, si la defines en tu controlador como false, siempre sera false, el valor que cambia es $rootScope.isLoading, por lo tanto no es necesario que definas tu ese valor

Comment: @sioesi tengo un pequeño problema aún: 

    <div class="loading" ng-show="isLoading"></div>

Mi problema es que me aparece el div loading nada mas cargar, no tendria q definir $rootScope.isLoading = false;  previamente?

Por lo que hay que poner el div asi:

    <div class="loading" style="display: none;" ng-show="!isLoading">

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear una directiva, que utilice el servicio $http de AngularJS (Angular 1) para obtener los llamados pendientes en proceso.

```
.directive('loadingSpinner',   ['$http' ,function ($http)
    {
        return {
            link: function ($scope, $elm, $attrs)
            {
                $scope.loadingRequests= function () {
                    var pendingRquests = $http.pendingRequests.length > 0 ? true :  false;
                    return pendingRquests 
                };

                scope.$watch($scope.loadingRequests, function (values)
                {
                    if(value){
                        elm.show();
                    }else{
                        elm.hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        };

    }]);
```

Luego tu HTML quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
<img src="../loading.gif" loading-spinner />
```